# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I tried setting my app in ember@2.5.0, but every time when I use store and try to use

```
this.store.findAll("user");
```

I always get the error saying Cannot read property 'type' of undefined.

Initialized the store, adapter and the model and server too.

**adapters/application.js**

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from 'ember-data/adapters/json-api';
export default JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    defaultSerialiser: "-default"
});
```

**models/user.js**

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr'
export default Model.extend({
    "name": attr()
});
```

and server side it is like

```
app.get("/users", function(req, res) {
    res.send({"name": "Surya"});
});
```

Getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at _pushInternalModel (store.js:1524)
at push (store.js:1501)
at finders.js:148
at Object.Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:678)
at _adapterRun (store.js:1733)
at finders.js:145
at tryCatch (ember.debug.js:53806)
at invokeCallback (ember.debug.js:53821)
at publish (ember.debug.js:53789)
at ember.debug.js:32054
```

Comment: There is typo in you adapter, it should be "defaultSerializer" not "defaultSerialiser", also the serializer name looks wrong to me(unless you actually named your serializer as -default.js). If you are trying to use default serializer then I assume you don't have to specify it in the adapter. But judging by the response you are providing, as @Lux metioned you should change your payload format if you really want to use jsonapi.

Comment: And you aren't returning jsonapi format, you are returning RESTAdapter/RESTSerializer format, and you are returning a single user, but you requested a collection of users.

Answer (score 1):

You use the JSONAPI serializer and adapter, but your response

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Surya"
  }
}
```

is not a valid [JSONAPI](http://jsonapi.org) response. It should be

```
{
  "data": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": "0",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Surya"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I need to send the response as a simple JSON and I can have only that kinda data only. But I tried to give this too. But still there was the same error.

Comment: Then use another serializer/adapter or write your own.

Comment: You should use REST adapter and serializer for this type of response, it's included in Ember.